# Getting multiple values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database setup in MySQL, with two different tables:

Table "matches"

```
ID   TEAM1ID   TEAM2ID   TIME   DATE
-------------------------------------
5    13        14        21:00  5 May
5    4         7        22:00  7 May
```

Table "teams"

```
ID   NAME             TEAMLEADER
-----------------------------------
13   GucciGang        Peter
4    Beatles          Peter
14   Beachboys        Peter
7    BackstreetBoys   Peter
```

I want to be able to assosicate the IDs in table "matches" with the team names from table "teams", so I can print it out on a matchpage.

My problem is that I can't the query to suit my needs.

My latest attempt:

```
SELECT matches.*, teams.name AS team1name
FROM matches
LEFT JOIN teams ON matches.team1ID = teams.id
UNION
SELECT matches.*, teams.name AS team2name
FROM matches
LEFT JOIN teams ON matches.team2ID = teams.id
```

This is obviously not ideal, as I get all the match data twice.
This gives me both names, but they are on seperate rows and they are both labeled `team1name`.

The result I'm looking for is getting something like this:

```
ID TEAM1ID   TEAM2ID  TIME   DATE   TEAM1NAME   TEAM2NAME
---------------------------------------------------------
5  13        14       21:00  5 May  GucciGang   BeachBoys
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the table twice:

```
SELECT    matches.*
,         Team1.name AS team1name
,         Team2.name AS team2name
FROM      matches
LEFT JOIN teams AS Team1
       ON matches.team1ID = Team1.id
LEFT JOIN teams AS Team2
       ON matches.team2ID = Team2.id
```

Note it's best practice to specify columns specifically, rather than `SELECT *`.